# Nginx - how to add a new location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 22.04. It is meant to run RStudio server and to deploy shiny apps and simple static webpages. I use nginx as my web server. This is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available`:

```
server {
        server_name example.org www.example.org;

        location /shiny/ {
           root /var/www/example/html;
           index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
           proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ https://$host/;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
           proxy_read_timeout 20d;
           rewrite ^/shiny/(.*)$ /$1 break;
           proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
           proxy_set_header X-RStudio-Root-Path /shiny;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
       }

       location /rstudio/ {
           root /var/www/example/html;
           index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
           rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8787;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
           proxy_set_header X-RStudio-Root-Path /rstudio;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
           proxy_read_timeout 20d;
       }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    ssl_certificate /home/user/ssl_example/example_org_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/ssl_example/example_org.key;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
}
```

Everything works perfectly. But now I don't know how to add a new simple HTML page. What I did was creating a new folder `/var/www/newpage/html/` with file `index.html` (`<p>New page.</p>`). I then added the following location block to the nginx's configuration file above:

```
       location /newpage/ {
           root /var/www/newpage/html;
           index index.html;
           #auth_basic "Restricted Content";
           #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
       }
```

I tested nginx for errors and restarted nginx.
However, the new webpage is not being served at `example.org/newpage` as I was expecting.

Clearly, I am missing something seemingly trivial. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nginx is looking for `/var/www/newpage/html/newpage/index.html` because of how `location` and `root` work. See [the `root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root). See also [the `alias` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) which may be one solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Richard. But I am unsure how to implement what you suggest. I tried just to replace `root` by `alias`, hoping that the page would be served at `example.org/newpage` (and the alias would redirect it to the right folder). But that didn't work (I restarted nginx). How would you do this?

Comment: You could try: `location /newpage { alias /var/www/newpage/html; }` or `location /newpage/ { alias /var/www/newpage/html/; }`

Comment: This worked! It was a basic mistake, but I learned something new today. Thank you!